# Run code on opened workbook not Macro sheet

Tags: vba, excel

**Aim:**

Create a new worksheet in a workbook that is opened by the Macro.

The Workbook opens but then Worksheet is added to the Marco file and not to the file I just automatically opened.

**Question:**

I'm not sure why the Worksheet "NewPortalFormula" is not added to the now open Workbook.

**Code:**

```
Dim vCheckName As String
vCheckName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" & objFile.Name
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(objFolder + "\" & objFile.Name)
' then activate it
wb.Activate
' Otherwise, workbook is already open, refer to it by name
'If worksheet exists delete it
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("NewPortalFormula").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Add new sheet to open workbook
wb.Activate
wb.Worksheets("NewPortalFormula").Add
wb.Save
wb.Close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Dim vCheckName As String
vCheckName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" & objFile.Name

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(objFolder + "\" & objFile.Name)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("NewPortalFormula").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set Ws = wb.Worksheets.Add
Ws.Name = "NewPortalFormula"
wb.Save
wb.Close
```

try to avoid using .activate or .select if possible. The code doesn't need to activate things to work with them.

***Edit from Comment added***

Comment: Btw: have you declared wb as Workbook? Why do you need the Path of the ActiveWorkbook? do you want to open the same workbook again?

Comment: Not declared wb as Workbook! That would help. Thanks for your formula. It makes a new sheet but does not rename it.

Comment: ooh, yes I forgot: instead of just "Ws = " you need to add a Set in front

Comment: If the added Worksheet ain't the first one in this Workbook, you could also define where it shall be inserted (in between of two sheets for example). just google "Worksheets.add-method"